# How to position floating ion-label inside ion-text-area?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my Ionic 5 app, I am displaying a text-area with a floating label like so:

[image: textArea before clicking]

Then when the user clicks on the `<ion-text-area>`, it appears like this:

[image: textArea after clicking]

Can someone please tell me how I can initially display the floating label nicely inside the text-area?

The label should be within the radius of the text-area when the page loads up.

Here is my current HTML & CSS:

```
<ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label position="floating">
      Please describe your issue to {{  mechanicToContact.name  }} here
    </ion-label>
    <ion-textarea 
        style="border-radius:30px;
        background: #6E73AA;
        padding: 5px";
        color="primary"
        rows="6"
        cols="20"
        required
        minlength="15">
    </ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Is this all your css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place your `ion-label` in "front" of your `ion-textarea` using `z-index` css attribute.

I suggest you do something like this to achieve relatively what you are looking for.

`component.html`

```
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label position="floating" class="position-label-inside">
      Please describe your issue to {{  mechanicToContact.name  }} here
    </ion-label>
    <ion-textarea 
        style="border-radius:30px;
        background: #6E73AA;
        padding: 5px;"
        color="primary"
        rows="6"
        cols="20"
        required
        minlength="15">
    </ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
```

`component.scss`

```
@keyframes slide-out {
  from {padding-left: 15px}
  to {padding-left: 0}
}

.position-label-inside {
  padding-left: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ion-item.item-has-focus {
  .position-label-inside {
    animation-name: slide-out;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    padding-left: 0!important;
  }
}

ion-textarea {
  z-index: 0;
}
```